# Is it possible to make an iPhone app fire a method from an external source

Tags: ios

Is there a way to send an iPhone a signal from a server to make it do something (like fire a specific method)?

I was thinking about push notifications, but the user would have to click to accept and fire the method from there. What if I want the phone to do something when the user is not around??

Ex: If someone loses their phone and we want to get some info from it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You could open a socket to your server (see [CFSocket](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html)) and fire methods according to what the socket receives. However, you'll need background permissions and your app could be rejected from the App Store.

According to the documentation, only specific app types are allowed to run in the
background:

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
- Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
- Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
- Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content
- Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

See *Implementing Long-Running Background Task* (page 58) in the [iPhone Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iphoneappprogrammingguide.pdf).